# asp.net opera print dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

in javascript the following code does not bring up the actual print dialog. The new window opens ok but no print dialog. IE/Chrome/mozilla are all fine.
Ive read all the usual timeout issues with opera and have tried i believe all possibilities of a solution.

Anyone have any idea what the solution is?

```
var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
var UserLoggedIn = $("#lblUser").text()
var now = new Date();
var strDateTime = [
    [AddZero(now.getDate()), AddZero(now.getMonth() + 1), now.getFullYear()].join("/"), [AddZero(now.getHours()), AddZero(now.getMinutes())].join(":"), now.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");
var Database = 'ProductionDatabase';
var windowName = 'Report';
var AuditPrintDetailEverypage = UserLoggedIn + ' Time : ' + strDateTime;
var AuditPrintDetailLastPage = '      Report ' + ' Source Database: ';
var WinPrint = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=300,top=300,right=500,bottom=500,width=1000,height=500,scrollbars=1');
WinPrint.document.write('<' + 'html' + '><head><link href="assets/css/Print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><title>' + AuditPrintDetailEverypage + '</title> </head><' + 'body  style="background:none !important"' + '>');
WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.write('          ' + AuditPrintDetailLastPage);
WinPrint.document.write('<' + '/body' + '><' + '/html' + '>');
WinPrint.document.close();

if (window.opera) {
    window.onload = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.print;
        }, 500);
    }
} else {
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```

Comment: Isnt `window.print` a method? Shouldn't you be calling `window.print()`?

Comment: And you're also setting the `onload` of `window`, not `WinPrint`. Don't you want to use `WinPrint` for all occurrences of `window` in that area of code? (keep `if (window.opera)` though, that one's fine)

Comment: `about:blank` is not really a cross-browser solution (f.ex. opera internally redirects these to `opera:blank`) - use `javascript:void(0)` instead.

Comment: here it tells you to not use the ()- http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?105277.html .

Comment: @pozs var windowUrl = javascript:void(0); when i made that change i get an error when i press my print function saying that Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'PrintGridData' is undefined

Comment: @ Ian - ive made that change but didnt help - i had that done before aswell. trust me ive been at this for a few days now!

Comment: wait! - now its working - ive got some formatting issues but unrelated to the item in question. ill add the answer below. thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the () is important for opera contrary to some sites.
hope this helps someone else. Answer credit to the guys above.

```
                    if (window.opera) {


                        WinPrint.onload = function () {
                            WinPrint.setTimeout(function () {
                                WinPrint.print();
                            }, 500);
                        }
```